# Gremlin.net.dll not found

Tags: asp.net, gremlin, gremlinnet

when moving from Gremlin.net 3.6.1, to 3.6.2 I get a FileNotFound Exception pointing to "rootOfProject"/Gremlin.net.dll
This is happening in my startup.cs when instantiating the GremlinClient

```
services.AddSingleton<GremlinClient>(s =>
            {
                GremlinServer server = new GremlinServer(hostname: "host", port: 443, enableSsl: true, username: $"collection", password: "password"]);
                var connectionPoolSettings = new ConnectionPoolSettings
                {
                    MaxInProcessPerConnection = 32,
                    PoolSize = 4,
                    ReconnectionAttempts = 4,
                    ReconnectionBaseDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
                };

                var socket = new Action<ClientWebSocketOptions>(o =>
                {
                    o.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                });
            return new GremlinClient(server, new GraphSON2MessageSerializer(), connectionPoolSettings, socket);
```

I have tried to copy the Gremlin.net.dll to the root folder of the project. And then it works.
I find it strange that the code is suddenly looking for the .dll at the root and not in the \bin folder

```
----------
{
    "developerMessage": "One or more errors occurred. (Could not find file 'C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Gremlin.Net.dll'.)",
    "userMessage": "Server error, contact system responsible",
    "code": "500",
    "httpStatusCode": 500,
    "exception": {
        "ClassName": "System.AggregateException",
        "Message": "One or more errors occurred.",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": {
            "ClassName": "System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
            "Message": "Could not find file 'C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Gremlin.Net.dll'.",
            "Data": null,
            "InnerException": null,
            "HelpURL": null,
            "StackTraceString": "   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)\r\n   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)\r\n   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)\r\n   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)\r\n   at System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Utils.GenerateUserAgent()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Utils.get_UserAgent()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.WebSocketConnection..ctor(IClientWebSocket client, WebSocketSettings settings)\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPool.CreateNewConnectionAsync()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPool.FillPoolAsync()",
            "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
            "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
            "ExceptionMethod": null,
            "HResult": -2147024894,
            "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
            "WatsonBuckets": null,
            "FileNotFound_FileName": "C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Gremlin.Net.dll",
            "FileNotFound_FusionLog": null
        },
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPool.FillPoolAsync()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPool.ReplaceDeadConnectionsAsync()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Utils.WaitUnwrap(Task task)\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPool..ctor(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ConnectionPoolSettings settings, ILogger`1 logger)\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.GremlinClient..ctor(GremlinServer gremlinServer, IMessageSerializer messageSerializer, ConnectionPoolSettings connectionPoolSettings, Action`1 webSocketConfiguration, String sessionId, Boolean disableCompression, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)\r\n   at Equinor.Vsm.Api.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<ConfigureServices>b__8(IServiceProvider s) in C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Startup.cs:line 205\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at MediatR.Wrappers.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Handle>g__Handler|0()\r\n   at Equinor.Vsm.Api.Application.Behaviors.DiscardGraphCacheBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Application\\Behaviours\\DiscardGraphCacheBehavior.cs:line 23\r\n   at Equinor.Vsm.Api.Application.Behaviors.ValidationBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Equinor.Vsm.Api.Controllers.V2.GraphController.MoveVertex(IGremlinQuerySource g, String projectId, MoveCommandDto moveCommand) in C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Controllers\\V2\\GraphController.cs:line 88\r\n   at lambda_method30(Closure, Object)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2146233088,
        "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
        "WatsonBuckets": null,
        "InnerExceptions": [
            {
                "ClassName": "System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
                "Message": "Could not find file 'C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Gremlin.Net.dll'.",
                "Data": null,
                "InnerException": null,
                "HelpURL": null,
                "StackTraceString": "   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)\r\n   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)\r\n   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)\r\n   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)\r\n   at System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Utils.GenerateUserAgent()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Utils.get_UserAgent()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.WebSocketConnection..ctor(IClientWebSocket client, WebSocketSettings settings)\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPool.CreateNewConnectionAsync()\r\n   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPool.FillPoolAsync()",
                "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
                "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
                "ExceptionMethod": null,
                "HResult": -2147024894,
                "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
                "WatsonBuckets": null,
                "FileNotFound_FileName": "C:\\SourceEquinor\\repos\\mad-vsm-api\\Equinor.Vsm.Api\\Gremlin.Net.dll",
                "FileNotFound_FusionLog": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full exception message, stack trace, and any inner exceptions that happened.

Comment: I'm having the same issue after upgrading to 3.6.2 version and calling Web.Api. The error message: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly "...\my-project\src\WebApi\Gremlin.Net.dll". The system cannot find the file specified`.

Comment: I guess it only happens when you run the application from Visual Studio. @Andreas did you find a way how to fix it?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution to fix it, other than to downgrade to 3.6.1

Comment: Please also share your `csproj` file. Do you also get this error if your create a completely new project without any other dependencies and then add Gremlin.Net there?

Comment: yes, I get it on a new project as well...

Answer (score 2):

Watch https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/2005. When it gets merged, the next release will contain a fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the functionality of 3.6.2 release, one way would be to add copy command inside .csproj file. This is a temporary solution while you wait for the next Gremlin version.
This issue only seems to happen for local environment, so could write something like this:

```
<Target Name="CopyDependencies" AfterTargets="Build">
<Copy Condition="$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT) == 'local'" SourceFiles="$(OutDir)Gremlin.Net.dll" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>
```

Note that you need to add the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: local` as well. The value you decide yourself, either it's local, development etc.

After that is done, add `Gremlin.Net.dll` file to the .gitignore, so that it is not tracked via source control.